# Javascript Issue with the document.form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run the code but i do not know what is causing the issue. It was working before, now when i try like this:

```
function makeUnderline(formName,editor) {
    var txt = window.prompt("Enter the text you wish to be underlined.", "Enter Text Here");
    if (txt != null) {
        document.formName.editor.value += "<u>" + txt + "</u>";
    }
    document.formName.editor.focus();
}

<input type="button" name="bUnderline" value=" underline " onClick="makeUnderline('formFaqs','answer');" alt="Use this button to create text that is underlined." title="Use 
this button to create text that is underlined.">
```

I am getting Error:

```
TypeError: document.formName is undefined

document.formName.editor.value += "<u>" + txt + "</u>";
```

Comment: including the javascript at the top of the page

Comment: do you mean document.forms[formName] instead of document.formName

Comment: What is the actual name of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the form name as a variable, you need to use bracket notation.

```
document.forms[formName].elements[editor].value += "<u>" + txt + "</u>";
```

Comment: Very Cool. Thanks Dude. This solved my issue and atleast i learned new thing here too. Cheers